# Difference between two statements C++

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, operator-overloading

Say I have a `class A` and have statements :

> A a1(1);
>
> A a2; a2(1);

What is the difference between the two statements?
I know first statement is straightforward but what is happening beside statement 2?

Comment: Hope you didn't mean `A a2 : a2(1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A a1(1);
```

This creates an instance `a1` of class `A` by calling a constructor with argument `1`.

```
A a2; a2(1);
```

This one's actually two statements. The first one, `A a2;`, creates an instance `a2` of class `A` by calling the default constructor of `A`. The second one, `a2(1);`, then invokes `A::operator()` with parameter `1` (or produces an error in case `A` does not define `operator()`).

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that, for most types, the second won't compile.

The first declares a variable and initialises it with value `1`. Initialising from a value like this is known as *direct initialisation*.

The second declares a variable and default-initialises it; then it tries to call it like a function, which only works if it has a suitable overload of `operator()`. In that case, it does whatever that operator is defined to do.

Perhaps you meant:

```
A a2; a2 = 1;
```

to default-initialise the variable, then assign the value 1. For trivial types, this would have the same effect as the first. For types which define constructors and assignment operators, it would depend on how those are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are special function that is called during creation of Objects.So accorrding to your Code the first statement compiles coz it have an matching constructor.But second doesnt create any instance coz u have provided implementation for it.

```
*class Shape
{
private:
    int cm;
public:
//    Shape()
//    {
//    }
//    Shape(int m_cm)
//    {
//        cm=m_cm;
//    }
};*
```

The above code can create an instance still it cant initiate value like 
s(7).